# Howto search through Properties of all kinds of types

Tags: c#, search, reflection

I have a base class called `Part` and derived classes like `Wire` or `Connector` and many more that inherit from `Part`.

Now I want to implement a search function that searches all Properties of the derived classes for a string.

If necessary that string should be tried to be converted to the type of the Property. The Properties can also be Lists and should be searched on the first level.

```
class Part 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Wire : Part
{
    public NumberWithUnit Diameter { get; set; }
    public Weight Weight { get; set; }
}

class Connector : Part
{
    public List<Part> ConnectedParts { get; set; }
}
```

I know how to generally search through the Properties of base types with Reflection like this

```
private bool SearchProperties<T>(T part, string searchString) where T : Part
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(part);
        if (value is string)
        {
            if (string.Equals(value, searchString))
                return true;
        }
        else if (value is int)
        {
            int v;
            if (int.TryParse(searchString, out v))
            {
                if(v == (int) value)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But that would be a long list of types and I have Properties of Type `Weight` for instance and many more. Is there some kind of general way to search without casting all types?

Comment: Might be a bit clunky, but I think interface definition like `IStringSearchable` for non-primitive types would help.  There's probably a better solution that doesn't need to touch each class though.

Comment: If the object being checked contains a property of a complex type, do you mean to check its properties too? I'm asking because in the question you are using the phrase "all Properties of the **derived** classes".

Comment: By derived classes I meant all classes that inherit from `Part`. But for a complex type it would be nice to check all the properties of that too, but only so far.

Answer (score 2):

Consider going the opposite direction with your conversion. Rather than converting your search string into each possible value, just convert the value into a string:

```
private bool SearchProperties<T>(T part, string searchString) where T : Part
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(part);
        if (value is IEnumerable)
        {
            // special handling for collections
        }
        else if(value != null)
        {
            string valueString = value.ToString();
            if (string.Equals(valueString, searchString))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Besides working pretty well for most built-in types, the only thing you have to do to get it to work for `Weight`, etc. is make sure they implement `ToString()`.

Another solution would be to use TypeDescriptor:

```
private bool SearchProperties<T>(T part, string searchString) where T : Part
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(part);
        if (value is IEnumerable)
        {
            // special handling for collections
        }
        else if(value != null)
        {
            object searchValue = null;
            try
            {
                searchValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value).ConvertFromString(searchString);
            } catch {}
            if (searchValue != null && object.Equals(value, searchValue))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

TypeDescriptor works well for most built-in types, but [requires extra work](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx) if you're dealing with custom types.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind: It does if they implement `ToString()`

Comment: But value can have different string representations, so IMO this route is not equivalent to the behavior OP is asking for.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Agreed. I've updated my answer with another possibility. Both have advantages and disadvantages, but the `ToString()` approach was simpler so I started with that one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should cover the most of the practical scenarios:

```
public static bool SearchProperties(object target, string searchString)
{
    if (target == null) return false;
    // Common types
    var convertible = target as IConvertible;
    if (convertible != null)
    {
        var typeCode = convertible.GetTypeCode();
        if (typeCode == TypeCode.String) return target.ToString() == searchString;
        if (typeCode == TypeCode.DBNull) return false;
        if (typeCode != TypeCode.Object)
        {
            try
            {
                var value = Convert.ChangeType(searchString, typeCode);
                return target.Equals(value);
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }
    }
    if (target is DateTimeOffset)
    {
        DateTimeOffset value;
        return DateTimeOffset.TryParse(searchString, out value) && value == (DateTimeOffset)target;
    }
    var enumerable = target as IEnumerable;
    if (enumerable != null)
    {
        // Collection
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
            if (SearchProperties(item, searchString)) return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Complex type
        var properties = target.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.GetMethod == null || property.GetMethod.GetParameters().Length > 0) continue;
            var value = property.GetValue(target);
            if (SearchProperties(value, searchString)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you one different idea to do it.

You could try something like that:

```
 private bool SearchProperties<T, W>(T part, W searchValue) where T : Part
   {
       var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
       foreach (var prop in props)
       {
           if (typeof(W) == prop.PropertyType)
           {
               var value = prop.GetValue(part, null);

               if (searchValue.Equals(value))
                   return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
```

You need to call the method like this:

```
    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Part p = new Part();
        p.Id = 2;
        p.Name = "test";
        p.bla = new Bla();

        SearchProperties<Part, int>(p, 2);
    }
```

And if you need to compare the complex properties (Weight, ...) by a different way from `GetHashCode` you could override the method `Equals` or the `==` operator.

```
   class Weight
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public override bool Equals(object obj)
       {
           return Id == ((Weight)obj).Id;
       }
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirements: One given search string should search *all* of the properties on the object.